# Attach two links of an object to two links of the robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am working with a humanoid robot for transportation of objects.

My objective is to simulate the grasping with both hands of a table from two different links.

As grasping is giving some problems I wanna attach the hand links to the table lnks in a certain manner.

In the first approach I developed a Spring-damper model, but I need a better attaching where a movement of one link, means the movement of the other.

I didnt find any solution.

All sugestions are welcome!!

Bests,

Julen U.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257279/attach--two-links-of-an-object-to-two-links-of-the-robot/) by [TheCamusean](https://answers.ros.org/users/29734/thecamusean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have already found a solution!

This package is super easy to use and let you attach all the links you need!!

https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher

Bests,

Julen U.

---

Originally posted by [TheCamusean](https://answers.ros.org/users/29734/thecamusean/) with karma: 51 on 2017-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0